# initState override for second, third page view etc

Tags: json, filter

I am using a script for a filter (Universal Filter). Because my boss wants specific projects to show when you first look at the page, I used initState and then specified which filter (from categories) to show.

BUT, when you filter a project and then hit the back button it goes right back to the initState instead of to what was last filtered. Is there any way to over-ride or change initState so that it is only active on a first page view?

Comment: initState where? Are you using flutter?

Comment: I have no idea what flutter is. the initState is in the script from the Universal Filter:  //**initstate:


                  initState:{sort:['Project Typest|asc'],filter:['Project Types|clear filter']}, // define what options need to be enabled on filter start

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.